# PyCharm - Unsupported Java Version - Critical Startup Error

Tags: pycharm

I was working on an issue for that I [changed the boot Java runtime of Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/switching-boot-jdk.html) from jdk-11 t0 jdk-8 using [Choose Runtime Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12836-choose-runtime) and restart the PyCharm. After restart I started getting following screen.

[image]

I tried resolution mentioned at [https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

1. [Find location](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) of the IDE files depends on the operating system, product and version.
2. Go to pycharm system (**idea.system.path**) directory.
3. Delete the file **pycharm.jdk**.
4. Restart Pycharm.